Inflicting Punishment On Individual For Engaging In Act Which Mubah
If an act which is Mubah is prohibited by decree of the ruler and if any individual engages in it, punished for acting with punishment like lashing, execution, or imprisonment. Are these laws considered a violation of Sharia and does this fall under the category of Judging other Sharia of Allah?
